# How to make this unbreakable - Minecraft 1.14.2 replaceitem Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the

```
replaceitem entity @a container.0 crossbow{display:{Name:"\"Paintball Cannon\"",Lore:["\"Put the fireworks in your offhand, and watch them go BOOM!\""]},Enchantments:[{id:quick_charge,lvl:3}]}"
```

command set up, but I do not know where to put the {unbreakable:1} tag to make the item unbreakable

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually matter where you put it, as long as you don't put it into a different tag.

These should all work:

```
/replaceitem entity @a container.0 crossbow{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"\"Paintball Cannon\"",Lore:["\"Put the fireworks in your offhand, and watch them go BOOM!\""]},Enchantments:[{id:quick_charge,lvl:3}]}
/replaceitem entity @a container.0 crossbow{display:{Name:"\"Paintball Cannon\"",Lore:["\"Put the fireworks in your offhand, and watch them go BOOM!\""]},Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:quick_charge,lvl:3}]}
/replaceitem entity @a container.0 crossbow{display:{Name:"\"Paintball Cannon\"",Lore:["\"Put the fireworks in your offhand, and watch them go BOOM!\""]},Enchantments:[{id:quick_charge,lvl:3}],Unbreakable:1}
```

It is important that the U in `Unbreakable` is capitalized.